# Scanning image with cover opened and I need to correct the brightness to match the one scanned from closed cover

Tags: scanner

I have a Epson Perfection v600 scanner and sometime I need to scan my images with the scanner cover open. This costs a difference between 5% to 9% darker in brightness of color. How do I correct this?

I have tried scanning them in a dark room at night and I even did a scanner calibration with the cover opened, but both methods didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: You would have to look very closely at the histograms. I did two scans (Epson V200, using iScan for Linux) and the difference is essentially in the very light tones (the black point and the average and median are nearly the same for both scans. On the other hand your scanner software possibly has a brightness setting?